# CountDownTimer vs AlarmManager

Tags: android, alarmmanager, countdowntimer

Are there any major differences between **CountDownTimer** and **AlarmManager**? I don't mean syntax or how to use it but wondering if there are such tasks when you certainly can say that I should use one of them, not another?
Simple example, I have to launch some action once a minute. What should I use? CountDownTimer or AlarmManager? How it depends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) generally is used for purposes where your application is closed or must [execute some repeating task(s)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29). It is also slightly less precise than `Timer` or `Handler`.

[`CountDownTimer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) is used more for running a specific task at a duration (`onFinish`), and being updated periodically until it executes (`onTick`).

In your specific case, I believe you should be using `AlarmManager`, since it can repeat indefinitely. If you want something to execute every second for 10 seconds, for example, use `CountDownTimer`.

Comment: "less precise" - that's interesting... But how less? Suppouse, I set repeating AlarmManager which fires every second and increase counter. How close it will be to one hour when counter will equal 3600?

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov Sorry i didn't see your comment sooner. It's impossible to say exactly how accurate it is, but other tasks take priority over it. I would suspect it would be no less accurate than one or two seconds over time.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I've already made simple test. Indeed, I cannot rely on AlarmManager time precision.

Comment: In my current application AlarmManager's precision is OK. The same as CountDownTimer. I can't remember how I did before when precision of AlarmManager was quite bad. So, I'd rather say that differnce between AlarmManger and CountDownTimer is very very subtle. It's more ideological question than practical.

Answer (score 2):

`CountDownTimer`

CountDownTimer will run in the context of your Activity. means It can be killed at any time, If your app is not on forground.

`AlarmManager`

A total different approach uses Sticky Intents. And tells your `Receiver`, after some time. It does not depends on the Activity's life Cycle.

So if you want to do some operation every minute, even your app is not on forground then you should use `AlarmManager`, otherwise `CountDownTimer` will do the job for you.

Comment: What if I create CountDownTimer at the service and close application?

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) :

> **Note**: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

So in your case is better to use CountDownTimer, since you don't want to do the action even if the app is closed.

Comment: What is the difference when I create CountDownTimer in service? I've closed my application and timer still working and performing some actions.

Comment: @VitaliiKorsakov Try to turn off the device - the service will be killed but I think Alarm Manager will work.